# Itunes Store Operation failed with Xcode 9.2

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

```
Im use version Xcode 9.2
When i upload ipa to itunes it crashes "Itunes Store Operation Failed"
I use Application Load Exam to get the information :
```

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)`enter code here`
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.apple.transporter.launcher.Application.start(Application.java:206)
    at com.apple.transporter.launcher.Application.main(Application.java:519)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: could not find needed OSGiFramework
    at com.apple.transporter.osgi.BootstrapHelper.setupClassLoader(BootstrapHelper.java:120)
    at com.apple.transporter.osgi.FelixOSGiBootstrapper.bootstrap(FelixOSGiBootstrapper.java:9)
    ... 6 more

```
how to fix
```

Comment: There seem to be a lot of issues with Xcode 9.2 Please try to use Xcode 9.1 and see if the error persists.

Comment: thanks you , Im dowloaded Xcode 9.1 and try it but not run

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Had the same issue, solved by removing the .itmstransporter directory,

```
rm -R ~/.itmstransporter
```

Comment: For me this fixed the upload through Xcode too. Not only the application loader.